# Solving Data by looping

Tags: r, loops

I have a Optimizer in R which gives me the optimum pts scored based on a set of criteria,

> Positions,# Players from Teams,Projections and Salary

It imports a  csv file that has a list of players hear is a small sample.  `

> Col A- Pos ...Col B-Name ...Col C- Salary...Col D- Team ...Col
>   E-AVGA1. Col F-AVGA2 etc all the way to AVG500

The code i have included Solves the Data that is in Column E how can i get it to "loop" and then solve for the data in Column F and so on without having to copy and paste and make 500 separate deals.

```
Pos     Name                    Salary  Team   AVGA1           AVGA2
PG      Russell Westbrook       11300   OKC    58.86094565     54.55   
PGSG    James Harden            11200   HOU    57.71092287     32.45
SFPF    Giannis Antetokounmpo   10500   MIL    56.05945537     16.11
PFC     Anthony Davis           11700   NOR    54.76162186     21.12
PGSG    Victor Oladipo           9000   IND    47.06204442     14.55

setwd("c:/r data/NBA/DK")
library('lpSolve')
data <-read.csv ("NBAAVG-A1.CSV")

#Convert salary to numeric
data$Salary <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",data$Salary), data$Salary)

#Add binary valeus for positions  'Constraint Vectors'
data <- cbind(data, X=1)
data <- cbind(data, PG=ifelse(data$Pos=="PG",1,0))
data <- cbind(data, SG=ifelse(data$Pos=="SG", 1,0))
data <- cbind(data, SF=ifelse(data$Pos=="SF", 1,0))
data <- cbind(data, PF=ifelse(data$Pos=="PF", 1,0))
data <- cbind(data, C=ifelse(data$Pos=="C", 1,0))
data <- cbind(data, PGSG=ifelse(data$Pos=="PGSG", 1,0))
data <- cbind(data, PGSF=ifelse(data$Pos=="PGSF", 1,0))
data <- cbind(data, SGSF=ifelse(data$Pos=="SGSF", 1,0))
data <- cbind(data, SFPF=ifelse(data$Pos=="SFPF", 1,0))
data <- cbind(data, PFC=ifelse(data$Pos=="PFC", 1,0))


#Objective Function. sum of proj pts
f.obj <- data$AVGA1

#Constraints
num_X <- 8
num_PG <- 1
num_SG <- 1
num_SF <- 1
num_PF <- 1
num_C <- 1
num_G <- 3
num_F <- 3
num_SGSF <- 2
num_PGSF <- 2
num_PFC <- 2
max_PGSG <- 4
max_PFC <-4
max_C <- 2
max_pg <- 3
max_PGC <- 4
max_team_cost <- 50000
cur_max <- 5000
max_player_from_a_team <- 4

#Constraints for max players from team
clubs <- sort(unique(data$Team))

team_constraint_vector <- c()
team_constraint_dir <- c()
team_constraint_rhs <- c()

for(i in 1:length(clubs)){
  temp <- data$Team==as.character(clubs[i])
  temp[temp==T] <- 1
  temp[temp==F] <- 0

  team_constraint_vector <- c(team_constraint_vector, temp)
  team_constraint_dir <- c(team_constraint_dir, "<=")
  team_constraint_rhs <- c(team_constraint_rhs, max_player_from_a_team)
}

solutions <- list()
solutionsMatrix <- matrix(, nrow=0, ncol=11)

for(i in 1:1){
  f.con <- matrix (c(data$X, data$PG + data$PGSG +data$PGSF, data$SG + data$PGSG + data$SGSF, data$SF + data$SGSF + data$SFPF + data$PGSF, data$PF + data$SFPF + data$PFC, data$C + data$PFC, data$PG + data$SG + data$PGSG + data$SGSF + data$PGSF, data$SF + data$PF + data$SGSF + data$SFPF+ data$PFC +data$PGSF, data$SG + data$PGSG + data$SGSF + data$SF + data$SFPF, data$PG + data$PGSF + data$PGSG + data$SF + data$SFPF +data$SGSF, data$PF + data$SFPF + data$PFC + data$C, data$C + data$PFC + data$PF,  data$C, data$PG, data$PG + data$C, data$PG + data$SG + data$PGSG, data$Salary, data$AVGA1, team_constraint_vector), nrow=(18+length(clubs)), byrow=TRUE)
  f.dir <- c("=", ">=", ">=", ">=", ">=", ">=", ">=", ">=", ">=", ">=", ">=","<=", "<=", "<=", "<=", "<=", "<=", "<=", team_constraint_dir)
  f.rhs <- c(num_X, num_PG, num_SG, num_SF, num_PF, num_C, num_G, num_F, num_SGSF, num_PGSF, num_PFC, max_PFC, max_C, max_pg, max_PGC, max_PGSG, max_team_cost, cur_max, team_constraint_rhs)

  x <- lp ("max", f.obj, f.con, f.dir, f.rhs, all.bin=TRUE)
  x

  solutions[[i]] <- data[which(x$solution==1),]
  solutionsMatrix <- rbind(solutionsMatrix, c("AVGB1", sum(solutions[[i]]$AVGA1), sum(solutions[[i]]$Salary), toString(solutions[[i]]$Name[1]), toString(solutions[[i]]$Name[2]), toString(solutions[[i]]$Name[3]), toString(solutions[[i]]$Name[4]), toString(solutions[[i]]$Name[5]), toString(solutions[[i]]$Name[6]), toString(solutions[[i]]$Name[7]), toString(solutions[[i]]$Name[8])))

  cur_max <- sum(solutions[[i]]$AVGA1) -.0001
}

solutions[[1]]

#Solutions Matrix Optimization
solutionsMatrix

write.csv(solutionsMatrix, file="S1/AVG1A.CSV")

##########################################
```

Comment: You can use a single `model.matrix` call to get dummy variables instead of all your `ifelse` statements. If you search the `[r]` tag for "dummy", you can find plenty of examples.

Comment: As for your question, turn your code into a function that takes the column you want as an input. Then it's trivial to loop over it. You won't be able to use `$` with a string column name, use `[[` instead. That is, `target = "F"`, `your_data$target` will not work, but `your_data[[target]]` will. Then you can do `for (target in c("E", "F", ...)){...}`.